# Classe com herança: error TS2554: Expected 5 arguments, but got 0

Tags: javascript, angular, herança

Tenho duas classes em Angular 4 que estão relacionadas por herança, no entanto ao fazer o *build* dá um erro:

> error TS2554: Expected 5 arguments, but got 0.

Classe Pai:

```
constructor(protected http: Http,
            private router: Router,
            protected jwtToken: JwtTokenService,
            private loadingService: LoadingService,
            protected requestOptions: DefaultRequestOptionsService) {}
```

Classe Filho:

```
constructor(private localStorage: LocalStorageService, 
            protected jwtToken: JwtTokenService, 
            protected http: Http) {
    super();
    this.check = this.jwtToken.token ? true : false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na classe filha está chamando o `super()`. Quantos argumentos está passando nele? Zero!. Na classe mãe o construtor tem 5 parâmetros. Se ela tem esses parâmetros, você precisa passar todos eles, passando zero está errado. Não posso afirmar o que deve passar em tudo, mas algo assim:

```
super(http, /* alguma coisa aqui */, jwtToken, /* alguma coisa aqui */, loadingService);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/OOP/Super.java).

Comment: Obrigado, mas nas versões anteriores não era necessário pois não?

Comment: Era sim. Não faz sentido não ser exigido, menos ainda mudar do nada.